# ¿Cómo extraer parte de una cadena si tan solo tengo donde quiero que termine?

Tags: java

Por ejemplo, tengo una cadena que contiene "Estado de cuenta: Inactivo" y quiero obtener como resultado **"Estado de cuenta: "** pero para cualquier cadena, en donde el fin de la cadena sea **": "**, es decir "Nombre: Juanchito Perez", quiero como resultado un String que contenga solo "Nombre: ", porque el problema radica en que no se que contiene la cadena, solo se su tamaño total y que tiene los caracteres ": " y el resto de información, la cual ahora no es necesaria.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Siempre demuestra que intentaste algo con tu codigo o intentaste averiguar algo. String.IndexOf es lo que buscas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes realizar un corte y después concatenar los `":"` si lo necesitas. `Split` realiza un corte justo en el caracter que indiques, en este caso `":"` .

> Ejemplo en Java.

```
String s1 = "Mi cadena contiene: dicho";
String[] cort = new String(s1).split(":");
System.err.println(cort[0].concat(":"));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Eso ha sido muy útil!!

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que especificar el lenguaje.

Si usas javascript el split es valido, en php seria

```
$data = "tu cadena: valor";
$data = explode(':',$data);
echo "el valor antes de dos puntos es: $data[0]";
```

Sin embargo esto cambia en sintaxis dependiendo del lenguaje que lo quieras.
si el caracter con el que lo quieres particionar los datos es dinámico saria de la siguiente manera:

```
$caracter = "@"; // puedes variar el carácter según sea el caso.
$data = "este es un correo @ mal escrito";
$data = explode($caracter, $data);
echo "esto es lo que hay antes del $caracter: $data[0];
```

Comment: Mil disculpas por no especificar. Utilizo Java

Comment: Si lees las etiquetas verás que es Java por lo tanto tu respuesta no aplica por sintáxis

Comment: No tiene sintaxis su pregunta, Podría estar leyendo de un json, una colección de objetos de javascript, etc.